# How to access a column from a sub query in outer query using Spark SQL

Tags: java, sql, apache-spark, dataset

In spark SQL, I executed the query

```
select 
  Retailer_country,
  max(sold) 
from (
  select 
    Retailer_country,
    count(*) as sold 
  from ProductInfo 
  where year=2013 and Product_type='Watches' 
  group by Retailer_country
)
```

to a dataset having columns

```
Retailer_country
Order_method_type
Retailer_type
Product_line
Product_type
Product
Year
Quarter
Revenue
Quantity
Gross_margin
```

It returns an exception

```
 org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: grouping expressions sequence is empty, and '__auto_generated_subquery_name.`Retailer_country`' is not an aggregate function. Wrap '(max(__auto_generated_subquery_name.`solds`) AS `max(solds)`)' in windowing function(s) or wrap '__auto_generated_subquery_name.`Retailer_country`' in first() (or first_value) if you don't care which value you get.;;
 Aggregate [Retailer_country#10, max(solds#77L) AS max(solds)#80L]
+- SubqueryAlias `__auto_generated_subquery_name`
+- Aggregate [Retailer_country#10], [Retailer_country#10, count(1) AS solds#77L]
  +- Filter ((cast(year#16 as int) = 2013) && (Product_type#14 = Watches))
     +- SubqueryAlias `productinfo`
        +- Relation[Retailer_country#10,Order_method_type#11,Retailer_type#12,Product_line#13,Product_type#14,Product#15,Year#16,Quarter#17,Revenue#18,Quantity#19,Gross_margin#20] csv
```

While I executed the same query in an online compiler with the same table structure, It returns

`USA|4`.

Sample Data:

```
USA|Fax|Outdoors Shop|Camping Equipment|Cooking Gear|TrailChef Deluxe Cook Set|2012|Q1 2012|59628.66|489|0.34754797
USA|Fax|Outdoors Shop|Camping Equipment|Cooking Gear|TrailChef Deluxe Cook Set|2013|Q1 2012|59628.66|489|0.34754797
USA|Fax|Outdoors Shop|Camping Equipment|watch|TrailChef Deluxe Cook Set|2013|Q1 2012|59628.66|489|0.34754797
USA|Fax|Outdoors Shop|Camping Equipment|watch|TrailChef Deluxe Cook Set|2013|Q1 2012|59628.66|489|0.34754797
USA|Fax|Outdoors Shop|Camping Equipment|watch|TrailChef Deluxe Cook Set|2013|Q1 2012|59628.66|489|0.34754797
UK|Fax|Outdoors Shop|Camping Equipment|watch|TrailChef Deluxe Cook Set|2013|Q1 2012|59628.66|489|0.34754797
UK|Fax|Outdoors Shop|Camping Equipment|watch|TrailChef Deluxe Cook Set|2013|Q1 2012|59628.66|489|0.34754797
USA|Fax|Outdoors Shop|Camping Equipment|watch|TrailChef Deluxe Cook Set|2013|Q1 2012|59628.66|489|0.34754797
UK|Fax|Outdoors Shop|Camping Equipment|Cooking Gear|TrailChef Deluxe Cook Set|2013|Q1 2012|59628.66|489|0.34754797
UK|Fax|Outdoors Shop|Camping Equipment|Cooking Gear|TrailChef Deluxe Cook Set|2012|Q1 2012|59628.66|489|0.34754797
```

How the result differs and how to display the `Retailer_country` in spark.
Any help to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have two aggreages. one for sub-query other for main query. the format of your query must be like below

```
select 
  Retailer_country,
  max(sold) 
from (
  select 
    Retailer_country,
    count(*) as sold 
  from ProductInfo 
  where year=2013 and Product_type='Watches' 
  group by Retailer_country)
group by Retailer_country
```

however, if we take a deeper look to your query, your subquery returns distinct Retailer_country because of group by aggregate. hence, you do not need to use outer max(sold) aggregate. As a result, your final query is actually this one:

```
select 
  Retailer_country,
  count(*) as sold 
from ProductInfo 
where year=2013 and Product_type='Watches' 
Group by Retailer_country
```

**Edit: According to provided comment**

```
select 
  Retailer_country,
  count(*) as sold 
from ProductInfo 
where year=2013 and Product_type='Watches' 
group by Retailer_country
Order by sold desc
limit 1
```

Comment: This query returning all the results. I just want the maximum of sold and its country like `USA|4`

Comment: can you provide us example data. because it seems that what you are trying to achive is contradicting with your query. The example raw data and desired output would be fine

Comment: I added some sample data

Comment: when you look at this data, can you understand anything? is it human readable? can you provide column names as well?

Comment: does uantity have any role for your query?

Comment: No The question is `Which country sold most Watches in the year 2013`

Answer (score 0):

Can't you then just 'order by sold desc' in the query above by Simonare and limit your records to 1?

```
select 
  Retailer_country,
  count(*) as sold 
from ProductInfo 
where year=2013 and Product_type='Watches' 
group by Retailer_country
order by sold desc
limit 1
```